# Chart Gtk Rendering failed

Tags: haskell, plot, charts

I'm on `Haskell` and using the `Chart` module.
There is no documentation for rendering in active `GTK` window. So I tryed by my own:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Easy
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Gtk

signal :: [Double] -> [(Double,Double)]
signal xs = [ (x,(sin (x*3.14159/45) + 1) / 2 * (sin (x*3.14159/5))) | x <- xs ]

main = renderableToWindow def 300 300 $ do
    layout_title .= "Amplitude Modulation"
    setColors [opaque blue, opaque red]
    plot (line "am" [signal [0,(0.5)..400]])
    plot (points "am points" (signal [0,7..400]))
```

But this is not correct, cause `ghc -o main main.hs` returns:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:7:8:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.StateT
                                    (Layout Double Double)
                                    (Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.State CState)
                                    ()
                                  -> t’
                with actual type ‘IO ()’
    Relevant bindings include main :: t (bound at main.hs:7:1)
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
    but its type ‘IO ()’ has none
    In the expression:
      renderableToWindow def 300 300
      $ do { layout_title .= "Amplitude Modulation";
             setColors [opaque blue, opaque red];
             plot (line "am" [signal [0, (0.5) .. 400]]);
             plot (points "am points" (signal [0, 7 .. 400])) }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = renderableToWindow def 300 300
            $ do { layout_title .= "Amplitude Modulation";
                   setColors [opaque blue, ....];
                   plot (line "am" [signal ...]);
                   .... }
```

So now my question: How to make a correct GTK rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderableToWindow` has type...

```
renderableToWindow :: Renderable a -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
```

... and so it doesn't take the `EC` computation you are trying to pass as the last argument. I believe the easiest solution is using [`toWindow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-gtk-1.5.1/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Gtk.html#v:toWindow), which will run the `EC` computation with the default state, convert its result to a `Renderable` and pass it to `renderableToWindow`:

> `toWindow :: (Default r, ToRenderable r) => Int -> Int -> EC r () -> IO ()`

```
main = toWindow 300 300 $ do
    layout_title .= "Amplitude Modulation"
    setColors [opaque blue, opaque red]
    plot (line "am" [signal [0,(0.5)..400]])
    plot (points "am points" (signal [0,7..400]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution.